# Julia: Extract unicode key from a character

Tags: unicode, julia

In Julian, I want to know the specific unicide-key of a character and save it to a variable. How to I do that?

I can for instance write Unicode characters in the `REPL` and it will gladly tell me their Unicode key.

```
julia> 'ë'
'ë': Unicode U+00EB (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

julia> 'e'
'e': ASCII/Unicode U+0065 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

How do i extract the `U+00EB` and `U+0065`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `codepoint`:

```
julia> codepoint('e')
0x00000065

julia> codepoint('ë')
0x000000eb
```